# Change UILabel Text inside UISegmentedControll according to its status

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

Is there any way to use UIAppearance to change the text color of a selected segment in UISegmented Controller and let other segments have same Color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0],                       UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],                                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
                                          [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14],                                                  UITextAttributeFont, 
                                          nil];
 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributesDictionary forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Docs:

[UIAppearance Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[setTitleTextAttributes:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setTitleTextAttributes%3aforState%3a)